# How to implement movingMarker of leaflet-moving-marker on Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet, markers

I'm trying to implement moving maker of leaflet-moving-marker but some errors occur.

```js
import {movingMarker} from 'leaflet-moving-marker'

    var myMovingMarker = L.movingMarker([[48.8567, 2.3508],[50.45, 30.523333]],
      [20000]).addTo(this.map);

myMovingMarker.start();
```

I have implemented as below and its is saying that movingMarker does not exist on type of import
.../@types/leaflet/index.

Comment: Angularjs or angular 2+?

Comment: angular 2+ (v11)

Comment: this plugin is unlikely to work with latest leaflet version as in the official github repo it runs only with `0.7.x` leaflet version.

Comment: How can i make a movement in leaflet in angular v11 ?

Comment: Please check the answer below and let me know if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`leaflet.animatedmarker`](https://github.com/openplans/Leaflet.AnimatedMarker). It is similar with the library you tried to use and is compatible with the latest leaflet version.

install the plugin:

```
npm i leaflet.animatedmarker
```

import the plugin:

```
import "leaflet.animatedmarker/src/AnimatedMarker";
```

when the component mounts create and save an instance of the plugin:

```
...
animatedMarker;

ngOnInit() {
   ...

    const line = L.polyline(
      [
        [40.6851, -73.94136],
        [40.68576, -73.94149],
        [40.68649, -73.94165]
      ],
      {
        color: "#02929b",
        weight: 1.5
      }
    ).addTo(map);

    this.animatedMarker = L.animatedMarker(line.getLatLngs(), {
      autoStart: false,
      icon
    });

    map.addLayer(this.animatedMarker);

    const group = new L.featureGroup([this.animatedMarker]);

    map.fitBounds(group.getBounds());
}

 

startAnimation() {
   this.animatedMarker.start();
}
```

Press the button to start the animation:

```
<button (click)="startAnimation()">Start animation</button>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-implement-movingmarker-on-angular-6sj1s)

Comment: Yes. You are right. I was having versions issues. I made an upgrade to Angular 11 too.

https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-wind-lx0rw?file=/src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Leaflet.MoveMarker](https://github.com/dekguh/Leaflet.MoveMarker)
that is a new plugin made by me. has quite complete features, you can see example code on github or [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/l-movemarker-basic-usage-fkdvty). for documentation you can see on the github repo of [Leaflet.MoveMarker](https://github.com/dekguh/Leaflet.MoveMarker).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).