# Integrate leafletjs AnimatedMarker into typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet

I installed leaflet typescript, and I found that there are problems when using leaflet non-typescript plugins.

For example, when using a plugin with typescript installed, I can successfully import this plugin:

install:

```
npm install --save leaflet-routing-machine
npm install --save @types/leaflet-routing-machine
```

angular component:

```
import 'leaflet-routing-machine';
import { Routing } from 'leaflet';
```

In this way, I can successfully use the plugin leaflet-routing-machine attached to the leaflet.

But when I use the [AnimatedMarker](https://github.com/openplans/Leaflet.AnimatedMarker) plugin, it doesn’t have typescript, so I don’t know how to use it.

I have tried the following methods but failed:

```
import 'leaflet.animatedmarker/src/AnimatedMarker';
import { AnimatedMarker, animatedMarker } from 'leaflet';
// Compilation will fail
```

or

```
 let AnimatedMarker = require('leaflet.animatedmarker/src/AnimatedMarker');
 console.log(AnimatedMarker);
```

or

```
import * as AnimatedMarker from 'leaflet.animatedmarker/src/AnimatedMarker';
   console.log(AnimatedMarker);
```

I wish to avoid using like:`import * as L from 'leaflet'` `L.AnimatedMarker`;
Although [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65492199/how-to-implement-movingmarker-of-leaflet-moving-marker-on-angular) method can successfully use non-typescript plugins.

Answer (score 1):

That plugin just seems to be a script to extend some L.* objects, like L.Marker.

Putting `import 'leaflet.animatedmarker/src/AnimatedMarker';` in the `main.ts` file should do the trick.

Like in this [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mc3zft?file=src/main.ts)